# How to monitor traffic of rails app on ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring

I have created a rails app on my ec2 instance. Today I have checked all the logs and I have found that someone is trying to access phpadmin( which is not actually on the path). I have noticed several attemps with different phpadmin paths. So its clear that someone tried to hack DB thorugh phpadmin.

After all this explaination.. here is my question.. How do I get alrets of such malicious attempts on my ec2 instance ? is that any free cloud monitoring service available where I can actually look that which IP address attempted what kind of paths ??

Answer (score 1):

While there are tools that will allow you to send logs to a service ([Paper Trail](https://papertrailapp.com/) has been a great online logging application that I've started to use and has a great free plan), in this case, I'd actually use something a bit different -- having a cron task set up so that it scans your application's log files, and then mail's you the output.

```
egrep '(myadmin|php|pgadmin)' /path/to/logfile | mail your@email.here
```

This has worked well for me in the past -- when I've needed alerting for something that isn't real-time critical for the server.